# cumulative count in previous rows in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 date   ID   flag
 Apr1   1    True
 Apr2   2    True
 May1   1    True
 May1   1    False
 May2   1    True
```

Wanted the cumulative count of `ID` in previous days (including that day) where the flag is `True`, like this:

```
 date   ID   flag   count
 Apr1   1    True   1
 Apr2   2    True   1
 May1   1    True   2
 May1   1    False  2
 May2   1    True   3
```

I tried boolean masking and `cumsum()`, but didn't get it to work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not `cumcount` you are looking for `groupby` and  `cumsum`

```
df.groupby('ID').flag.cumsum().astype(int)
Out[362]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
Name: flag, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you need:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(by=['ID'])['flag'].cumsum().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    date    ID  flag    count
0   Apr1    1   True    1
1   Apr2    2   True    1
2   May1    1   True    2
3   May1    1   False   2
4   May2    1   True    3
```

Comment: This will cast the final result to `float`

Comment: what is the different